# PerformancePoint Dashboard Designer will not work

Tags: dashboard, sharepoint-2013

I am using Sharepoint 2013 and trying to get PerformancePoint Dashboard Designer to work. It's supposed  to be a one click run thing. I have an admin account.

When I launch Sharepoint Dashboard designer from Sharepoint in IE (as the admin user), the "Data Source" button is blanked out. When I try to go to Options > Server and type in the Sharepoint server name I get this:

> The URL must be in one of the following zones: Local, Intranet, or Trusted. http://servername

I have gone back into IE to change the security settings, but there is a gold key right next to each Internet, Local Intranet, Trusted sites, and restricted sites. Also the "Sites" button and the custom level button are inactive (grayed out).

More than one way to skin a cat, I launch Dash Design from my desktop. In this instance it seems to connect correctly. It says my username (and Admin)  and connected to the server on the lower left hand corner of the tool. However when I try to add a data source it tells me

> "Access denied. You do not have permissions to connect to the server. Please contact your system administrator."

Answer (score 0):

If you dig into the logs you will most likely find authentication errors.  PerformancePoint requires the use of windows tokens - not claims.  You will need two things to make it work:

- Configure constrained delegation for the service
- Ensure the Claims to windows token service is running (C2WTS).